# Small doubt about the term "error of smaller order"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am reading Mathematical analysis by Tom Apostol. In chapter 12 , section 4, I am stuck on one term 'smaller order'. Author gives first order Taylor formula for approximating $f(c+h) - f(c)$ by $f'(c)h$ which is 
  $$f(c+h)=f(c)+ f'(c)h + hE_{c}(h)$$ and says that error $hE_{c}(h)$ is of smaller order than $h$ as $h$ goes to $0$. Can someone please explain what he want to say by smaller order here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like he is *defining* this to mean $E_c(h)\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ (paragraph below equation (4)). Equivalently, we can define the term to be $r_c(h):= hE_c(h),$ then require that $r_c=o(h)$ as $h\rightarrow 0$, which means that $r_c/h\rightarrow 0.$ This tells us that $r_c(h)=hE_c(h)$ goes to zero faster than $h$ as $h\rightarrow 0,$ which might help motivate the terminology a bit for you.

Comment: But normally one would then say that the error term has a higher order than the one of the linear term.

Comment: I agree, I don’t really like that terminology, it seems backwards from what I would use. That’s just what I gained from context when I opened the book and looked at the definition.